# How to handle 'nan' in confusion matrix

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to evaluate a classifier which I run on several datasets. In my dataset, it is possible that there are no positive events. Whenever my classifier detects zero positive events as well, my sensitivity (TP/P) is nan and my f1 score will be zero. However, this is a positive result for the classifier, which I want the results to express in some way.

Additionally, when I average these metrics over different datasets, should I ignore these nan values and the entry? or include them in someway.

I have thus far not come across with examples having 0 TP and 0 P values, which feels strange as it must happen ever so ofter.

Much appreciated!